# About quantileTiming function of Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

As described in [ClickHouse docs](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#quantiletimingweighted-level-x-weight) `quantileTiming` function accepts an expression returning float type number.

I got an error when i passed a float field to the function:

Query:

```sql
SELECT quantileTiming(0.5)(number / 2) FROM numbers(10)
```

```
Received exception from server:
StatusCode 500 Response Code: 43, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Argument for function quantileTiming must be integer, but it has type Float64 (version 19.5.3.8)
 Err <nil>`
```

Can someone tell me what's the problem? And what's the difference between quantile and quantileTiming. What alg does quantileTiming use? Thanks.

Comment: This example is working fine on version '19.17.5 revision 54428', it looks like you use version CH that works wrong with float-type - look at [change log](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/changelog/) where described some fixes of *quantileTiming*-function.

Comment: thanks very match. it really resolve my problems.  and what alg does quantileTiming use? i'm not familiar with cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `number / 2` is not of type Integer but Float.

Also as [said in docs](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_function-quantiletiming):

> The function expects input values in unix timestamp format in
>   milliseconds, but it doesn't validate format.

From your question it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You should pass unix timestamp in milliseconds instead of `number / 2`.

AFAIK `quantile` is used to calculate standard quantiles as we know it from statistics. And `quantileTiming` is optimised for computing quantiles of page loading times. As the use case is more narrow, it should be more precise at least. You can find implementations in [ClickHouse repo](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/tree/9a2b781/dbms/src/AggregateFunctions) in Quantile*.h files.